# JSON - Make popup navigate to Google

Tags: json, google-chrome, popup

I'm trying to write a Chrome extension where, when clicked, it will drop down Google.  For now, it only loads a local .html file.  Here is the code I currently have:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "theName",
"description": "TheDesc",
"version": "1.0",

"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon.png",
"default_popup": "http://www.google.com",
"default_title": "Tooltip"
},
"permissions": [
"activeTab",
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
]
}
```

I have 4 files in my folder:  icon.png, manifest.json, popup.html, & popup.js.  I am using the "Getting Started" tutorial from https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted as a template, as I am extremely new to all of this (vb6 programmer for years).

Edit:
I finally got it to open a webpage in the little popup.  Now, I need to grab the Title of the current tab's URL, remove the spaces from it, trim it down to 30 characters max, assign it to a string, then navigate to www.website.com/STRING.  What I'm thinking is the extension needs to create a new popup.html each time, but that could be taxing on the server.  Perhaps this can be done straight from the extension?  I don't have a clue.  Just guessing at this point.

Comment: so what exactly is the question?

Comment: still doesn't feel like an answerable question. read SO Q&A for how to ask a question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask